# Macbook | Mouse and Trackpad Options

Tags: mouse, trackpad

Is there a way to set the options for scrolling in the following way :

**Use this option when the trackpad is used for scrolling and navigation | Keep this option checked.**
"Move Content in the direction of finger moment when scrolling or navigating"

And when the **mouse** is being used, I want the above option to be **unchecked**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are talking about the setting that, for me (British English) shows in Settings > Trackpad > Scroll & Zoom > "Scroll direction: natural".

[This discussion](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1194820) talks about this issue, and several people mention [Scroll Reverser](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/37872/scroll-reverser).  It has separate options for "Reverse Trackpad" and "Reverse Mouse".  (I haven't tested your scenario, but I have used this software for other reasons.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did check out the app later on the same day and it works.

Comment: Great! If the answer was useful, would you consider voting on it and accepting it? (See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)). This'll help others who might have the same question in the future.